# Is there a way to configure variable fill_values for interp1d?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I don't know if my question is very clear, my apologies.
This is the example that I will be using to ilustrate what I need to do:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
intertest = interp1d([500, 1000], [-1, 1])
mylist = [400, 500, 1000, 1100]
list2 =intertest(mylist)
print(list2)
```

Obviously, I get a ValueError because there are values (400 and 1100) outside of the interpolation range. But I was wondering if it was possible to set a configuration that would make the values outside the range to go to the closest value inside the range (400 would go to 500 and 1100 would go to 1000), in that case, the result would be [-1, -1, 1, 1].

In the real case, the data is really large so it would be better if the solution were in the interpolation configuration, because it can be applied directly to the data array.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the list before `interp1d`: `[min(x_max, max(x_min, s)) for s in mylist_tmp]`

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
x_min=500
x_max=1000
intertest = interp1d([x_min, x_max], [-1, 1])
mylist_tmp = [400, 500, 1000, 1100]
mylist=[min(x_max, max(x_min, s)) for s in mylist_tmp]
list2 =intertest(mylist)
print(list2)
```

Comment: This does help but I was hoping to find a way to do this on the function interp1d itself or something like that. The real data that I'll be working with are matrixes so modifying them would not be my first choice.